# Spliting a string with multiple delimiters from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I need to split a string by multiple delimiters.

My string is `var str = "2$4@3*5"`

My array of delimiters (separators) is `var del = ["$","@", "*"]`

I'm using a regular expression but it is not working.

`str.split(new RegExp(del.join('|'), 'gi'));`

The results should be `["2","4","3","5"]`

However I'm getting an error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to repeat`

When I remove the `*` the resulting array is `["2$3',"3", "5"]`

How can I split with multiple delimiters from an array of delimiters?

and why does this not work with `$` and `*`?

Comment: because $ and * have special meaning in regex ... try `\\$` `\\*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters first - `replace` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/10221765):

```js
var str = "2$4@3*5";    
var del = ["$", "@", "*"];    

const res = str.split(new RegExp(del.map(e => e.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|"), "gi"));
    
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank works great thank you!

Comment: I would leave `RegExp.escape` separate, like in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/6231376), and map like `del.map(RegExp.escape)`. Much more readable.

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't need to add it to the object, it's easier - plus you could just construct your own function @TeWu.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

I passed in the Regex expression in split.

```js
var str = "2$4@3*5"

var res=  str.split(/[$,@,*]+/)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The array of delimiters needs to be dynamic which is why I prefer Jack's answer in this case.